# Error on loading maps after splash screen

Tags: android, google-maps, android-layout, splash-screen, google-maps-api-2

I've got a typical problem here. I've tried loading Android maps successfully and also tried loading splash screens successfully.

Now when i try to load maps after a splash screen i get the following exception

```
04-08 00:35:46.890: E/AndroidRuntime(19891): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-08 00:35:46.890: E/AndroidRuntime(19891): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.R$styleable
04-08 00:35:46.890: E/AndroidRuntime(19891):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMapOptions.createFromAttributes(Unknown Source)
04-08 00:35:46.890: E/AndroidRuntime(19891):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment.onInflate(Unknown Source)
04-08 00:35:46.890: E/AndroidRuntime(19891):    at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4242)
04-08 00:35:46.890: E/AndroidRuntime(19891):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:673)
04-08 00:35:46.890: E/AndroidRuntime(19891):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:739)
04-08 00:35:46.890: E/AndroidRuntime(19891):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
04-08 00:35:46.890: E/AndroidRuntime(19891):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
04-08 00:35:46.890: E/AndroidRuntime(19891):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
04-08 00:35:46.890: E/AndroidRuntime(19891):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:251)
04-08 00:35:46.890: E/AndroidRuntime(19891):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1835)
04-08 00:35:46.890: E/AndroidRuntime(19891):    at com.example.androidmapsv2.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:53)
04-08 00:35:46.890: E/AndroidRuntime(19891):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
04-08 00:35:46.890: E/AndroidRuntime(19891):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
04-08 00:35:46.890: E/AndroidRuntime(19891):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
04-08 00:35:46.890: E/AndroidRuntime(19891):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
04-08 00:35:46.890: E/AndroidRuntime(19891):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
04-08 00:35:46.890: E/AndroidRuntime(19891):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
04-08 00:35:46.890: E/AndroidRuntime(19891):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-08 00:35:46.890: E/AndroidRuntime(19891):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-08 00:35:46.890: E/AndroidRuntime(19891):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
04-08 00:35:46.890: E/AndroidRuntime(19891):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-08 00:35:46.890: E/AndroidRuntime(19891):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-08 00:35:46.890: E/AndroidRuntime(19891):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:787)
04-08 00:35:46.890: E/AndroidRuntime(19891):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:554)
04-08 00:35:46.890: E/AndroidRuntime(19891):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-08 00:35:49.703: I/Process(19891): Sending signal. PID: 19891 SIG: 9
```

I've followed all the basic procedures to embed maps and to display splash screens since I've succeeded when i tried implementing them separately.

I've made sure the google-play-services jar and the android-supportv4 jar are in libs folder and are referenced properly.

---

MainActivity.java

---

```
package com.example.androidmapsv2;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnMapLongClickListener;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
//import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.PolylineOptions;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
//import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
//import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnMapClickListener,
        OnMapLongClickListener, LocationListener {

    final int RQS_GooglePlayServices = 1;
    private GoogleMap myMap;

    Location myLocation;
    TextView tvLocInfo;
    LocationListener myLocationListener;

    double CURRENT_LAT = 0.0;
    double CURRENT_LON = 0.0;

    double PREVIOUS_LAT = 0.0;
    double PREVIOUS_LON = 0.0;

    LocationManager locationManager;
    String provider;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        tvLocInfo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.locinfo);

        FragmentManager myFragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        MapFragment myMapFragment = (MapFragment) myFragmentManager
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        myMap = myMapFragment.getMap();

        myMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        // myMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
        myMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
        // myMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);
        // myMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN);

        // Getting LocationManager object
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        // Creating an empty criteria object
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

        // Getting the name of the provider that meets the criteria
        provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);

        if (provider != null && !provider.equals("")) {

            // Get the location from the given provider
            Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 20000, 1, this);

            if (location != null) {
                onLocationChanged(location);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Location can't be retrieved",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No Provider Found",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        myMap.setOnMapClickListener(this);
        myMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menu_legalnotices:
            String LicenseInfo = GooglePlayServicesUtil
                    .getOpenSourceSoftwareLicenseInfo(getApplicationContext());
            AlertDialog.Builder LicenseDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                    MainActivity.this);
            LicenseDialog.setTitle("Legal Notices");
            LicenseDialog.setMessage(LicenseInfo);
            LicenseDialog.show();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();

        int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil
                .isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getApplicationContext());

        if (resultCode == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "isGooglePlayServicesAvailable SUCCESS", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
        } else {
            GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode, this,
                    RQS_GooglePlayServices);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onMapClick(LatLng point) {
        tvLocInfo.setText(point.toString());
        myMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(point));
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapLongClick(LatLng point) {
        tvLocInfo.setText("New marker added@" + point.toString());
        myMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(point).title(
                point.toString()));
        // Polyline line =
//      myMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions().add(
//              new LatLng(12.97202903709172, 80.21577659994364),
//              new LatLng(12.978670181826473, 80.2174412459135))
//              .geodesic(true));

        double lat = point.latitude;
        double lon = point.longitude;

        System.out.println("lat = "+lat);

        CURRENT_LAT = lat;
        CURRENT_LON = lon;

        tvLocInfo.setText("lat: " + lat + "\n" + "lon: " + lon);

        LatLng latlng = new LatLng(lat,
                lon);

        myMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latlng));

        if (CURRENT_LAT != 0.0 && CURRENT_LON != 0.0 && PREVIOUS_LAT != 0.0
                && PREVIOUS_LON != 0.0) {
            myMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions().add(
                    new LatLng(PREVIOUS_LAT, PREVIOUS_LON),
                    new LatLng(CURRENT_LAT, CURRENT_LON)).geodesic(true));
        }
        PREVIOUS_LAT = CURRENT_LAT;
        PREVIOUS_LON = CURRENT_LON;

    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location myLocation) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // if (myLocationListener != null) {
        // myLocationListener.onLocationChanged(myLocation);

        double lat = myLocation.getLatitude();
        double lon = myLocation.getLongitude();

        CURRENT_LAT = lat;
        CURRENT_LON = lon;

        tvLocInfo.setText("lat: " + lat + "\n" + "lon: " + lon);

        LatLng latlng = new LatLng(myLocation.getLatitude(),
                myLocation.getLongitude());

        myMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latlng));

        if (CURRENT_LAT != 0.0 && CURRENT_LON != 0.0 && PREVIOUS_LAT != 0.0
                && PREVIOUS_LON != 0.0) {
            myMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions().add(
                    new LatLng(PREVIOUS_LAT, PREVIOUS_LON),
                    new LatLng(CURRENT_LAT, CURRENT_LON)).geodesic(true));
        }
        PREVIOUS_LAT = CURRENT_LAT;
        PREVIOUS_LON = CURRENT_LON;

        // }
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String arg0, int arg1, Bundle arg2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```

---

### SplashScreen.java

```
package com.example.androidmapsv2;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;

public class SplashScreen extends Activity {

    private static final int SPLASH_TIME = 3 * 1000;// 3 seconds

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splashscreen);

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this,
                        MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);

                SplashScreen.this.finish();

                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);

            }
        }, SPLASH_TIME);

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
              @Override
              public void run() {
                     } 
                }, SPLASH_TIME);

    }


    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        this.finish();
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

---

### activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/locinfo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

---

### splashscreen.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:background="@drawable/splash"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
</RelativeLayout>
```

---

### AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.androidmapsv2"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.example.androidmapsv2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" >
    </permission>

    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.androidmapsv2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyAkfu2ZAgQfO6iQ_ldkOAaVyMOPDmq_Lg0" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.example.androidmapsv2.SplashScreen"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.example.androidmapsv2.MainActivity" >
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="My Key" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

pls see the below structure

[image]

I've also used the latest API key and other basic things.

Answer (score 0):

For me it still looks like a problem with the `google-play-services` referencing.

**1.** could you please varify that you have the selected (`red`) files in you dependencies folder (`green`).

[image]

**2.** please verify that you have this line in your `project.properties` file that sits in the root of you project folder:

```
android.library.reference.1=../../android-sdk_r17-windows/extras/google/google_play_services/libproject/google-play-services_lib
```

or something similar.

Comment: yes.. ive selected the same as show above in by package screenshot. and yes i have it referenced in my properties file.
I had maps working when i tried without the splash screens.
But for now on startup splash screen loads but a forced close error is thrown due to above exception.

Answer (score 0):

Previous version of goolge map has been depreciated.You need to use new Api v2 for development.

You have given your key twice in Manifest.xml apart from that,
Now extends your MainActivity to Fragment Activity 
and replace

```
FragmentManager myFragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
MapFragment myMapFragment = (MapFragment) myFragmentManager
        .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
myMap = myMapFragment.getMap();
```

By---

```
map = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                .getMap();
```

and inside activity_main.xml replace `"com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"`

by-----`"com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportedMapFragment"`

and you are GOOD TO GO.